# The controller for path 'xxx' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: iis, odata, wcf-data-services

My company has a web application that implements both OData (System.Data.Services.DataService) and WebAPI endpoints to allow another application to communicate with it. We have one customer who recently upgraded a working system to the latest release and started having problems with the OData part of the interface, where the WebAPI endpoints are working just fine. Their system is using HTTP. We have many other customers running the same version of the software without issue, so I believe there is some system configuration issue on the customer's server that is causing the issue, but I have been unable to figure out what it is. The exception occurs in the server's code:

```
Message=The controller for path '/RemoteDataService.svc/Users()' was not found or does not implement IController.
Relative Path=/RemoteDataService.svc/Users()?$filter=((lDeleted%20eq%200)%20and%20(lActive%20ne%200))%20and%20(nUserUID%20eq%20guid'915f9722-3175-4e4d-a571-4a478e8e5172')&$top=1&$select=cFirstName,cLastName
Source=System.Web.Mvc
Stack=   at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Since this application works on literally hundreds of other systems, it is not a matter of a wrong namespace, or misspelled controller name, or failure to implement an interface as I have seen other posts suggest regarding apps under development. So my question is, are there settings in IIS or the file system or network or somewhere else that could potentially cause this exception to occur? Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue due to the presence of a Web API related assembly in the application that was not properly referenced. It also needs to be set in the `web.config` file of the site in IIS:

```
<system.webServer> 
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

In addition, I've seen other people give a workaround to embed the class into the namespace (If this reason has been ruled out, you can ignore it). Also, the error caused by the version upgrade, someone try to rebuild a project and import the source code, and then it can return to normal.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The web.config file already contains this entry. I cannot change the namespace for the class. This production release of the application is in use by many other customers without issue. It must have something to do with the configuration on this specific system.

Comment: But this error doesn't seem to have anything to do with the IIS configuration.